# What type of noun phrase is "the Smithsonian of hand-me-downs"?

Tags: phrases, nouns, terminology

Is there a specific type of noun phrase for a phrase such as "the Smithsonian of hand-me-downs"?

Comment: It's called a 'fused-head' noun phrase in which the adjective "Smithsonian" combines (fuses) the function of head with that of dependent (in this case modifier).

Comment: Are you interested in the grammar of the phrase or in the phrase as a figure of speech, like "the Waldorf Astoria of fleabag hotels"?

Comment: I understand it to mean "the Smithsonian hand-me-down of some set of 'hand-me-downs".

Answer (score -1):

It is an **adjective phrase** as the main noun in the phrase is "Smithsonian". And, Smithsonian is a proper adjective (proper noun turned into an adjective) in this case.